# Building a document functionally and based on input value in a Play 2 controller in Scala and ReactiveMongo

Tags: scala, functional-programming, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

I've a Play controller Action that edits a document in MongoDB using ReactiveMongo. The code is shown below. Both name and keywords are optional. I'm creating a temp `BSONDocument()` and adding tuples to it based on if name and keywords exist are not empty. However, `tmp` is currently mutable(is a `var`). I'm wondering how I can get rid of the `var`.

```
    def editEntity(id: String, name: Option[String], keywords: Option[String]) = Action          {

    val objectId = new BSONObjectID(id)

    //TODO get rid of var here
    var tmp = BSONDocument()

    if (name.exists(_.trim.nonEmpty)) {
      tmp = tmp.add(("name" -> BSONString(name.get)))
    }

    val typedKeywords : Option[List[String]] = Utils.getKeywords(keywords)
    if (typedKeywords.exists(_.size > 0)) {
      tmp = tmp.add(("keywords" -> typedKeywords.get.map(x => BSONString(x))))
    }

    val modifier = BSONDocument("$set" -> tmp)
    val updateFuture = collection.update(BSONDocument("_id" -> objectId), modifier)
}
```

**UPDATE** After looking at the solution from @Vikas it came to me what if there are more (say 10 or 15) number of input `Option`s that I need to deal with. Maybe a `fold` or `reduce` based solution will scale better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code you're adding an empty `BSONDocument()` if none of those `if` conditions matched? `val modifier = BSONDocument("$set" -> tmp)` will have an empty `tmp` if `name` was `None` and `typedKeyWords` was `None`. Assuming that's what you want here is one approach to get rid of transient `var`. also note having a `var` locally (in a method) isn't a bad thing (sure I'll still make that code look bit prettier)

```
 val typedKeywords : Option[List[String]] = Utils.getKeywords(keywords)
 val bsonDoc = (name,typedKeywords)  match{
  case (Some(n),Some(kw) ) => BSONDocument().add( "name" -> BSONString(n)) .add(("keywords" -> kw.map(x => BSONString(x))))
  case (Some(n), None) => BSONDocument().add( "name" -> BSONString(n))
  case (None,Some(kw)) => BSONDocument().add(("keywords" -> kw.map(x => BSONString(x))))
  case (None,None) => BSONDocument()

}
val modifier = BSONDocument("$set" -> bsonDoc)
```

Comment: your solution will work and is certainly better than my initial solution. You are correct, if nothing has changed, there is no need to edit the document. I can just return.  I'm wondering if a pattern match will scale to say 10 parameters? Maybe a foldLeft on a BSONDocument ?